# Change default value of an attribute in constructor class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, default-constructor

I have a class Action below. Default values for *_actionOver* and *_peopleAffected* are defined.

```
class Action {
    constructor(staffName, description, actionOver, peopleAffected){
        this._staffName=staffName;
        this._description=description;
        this._actionOver=false;
        this._peopleAffected=0;
    }
```

Now I define a new object of this  class and change values for *actionOver* and *_peopleAffected*

```
let a= new Action ('Raul', 'Goal 1: Qaulity Education', true,10);
```

When I print this in console

```
console.log(a._actionOver);   *// gives false
console.log(a._peopleAffected);  *// gives 0*
```

Should not it give *true* and *10* as output, if i have changed values in object. If not how do I change default value of an constructor attribute?

Comment: Check the [reference on default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). Right now you're overwriting the parameters instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just ignoring the constructor arguments and always assign the same initial value.
I guess you actually wanted to use [default parameter values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)?

```
class Action {
    constructor(staffName, description, actionOver = false, peopleAffected = 0){
//                                                ^^^^^^^^                ^^^^
        this._staffName = staffName;
        this._description = description;
        this._actionOver = actionOver;
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^
        this._peopleAffected = peopleAffected;
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning a default value, you're just assigning a value and ignoring the values passed as arguments.

Once you defined your default:

```
    this._actionOver=false;
```

You must check if other values have been passed via arguments and overwrite the defaults:

```
    this._actionOver=false;
    if (actionOver) this._actionOver = actionOver;
```

You can do a one liner:

```
   this._actionOver = actionOver || false;
```

Or just use function parameter defaults:

```
    constructor(staffName, description, actionOver = false, peopleAffected = 0){
        // ....
        this._actionOver=actionOver;
    }
```

Comment: oh i see now. Thanks for the help.